# Conditional test and aliases

Tags: apt, bash

Looking for a bit of help as I can't get this to work. I want to test if `apt` is installed on the system and then create aliases for it if so.

I came up with the following command, but it doesn't work, as I've determined that the `[ ]` is coming up true, no matter if `apt` is there or not.

```
if [ -x $(which apt) &> /dev/null ]; then alias ai='sudo apt install';   alias ar='sudo apt remove';   alias as='apt search';   alias ah='apt history';   alias au='sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade'; fi   # apt
```

I want the aliases to be created only if `apt` is there. Can you think of the correct test that I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-x` is a *file test* whereas `$(which apt) &> /dev/null` is a command.

To use `-x` you could do

```
if [ -x /usr/bin/apt ]; then
```

If you want to search using `which`, you could do

```
if [ -x "$(which apt)" ]; then
```

however you could instead use the exit status of the `which` command directly:

```
if which apt &> /dev/null; then ...
```

Be aware that `which` is not always definitive - see for example [Why not use “which”? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Comment: Perfect . Thanks for the warning, that's good to know also (though I'm not too worried about that as these are not for enterprise production environments, just some useful shortcuts to get things done a bit more quickly on my home systems. ).